# Javascript this object does not support this action

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog, window

The error:

> "this object does not support this action"

The goal is to close a child window upon clicking on a button in a page

Button code of the child window

```
button type="submit" onclick ="window.parent(dlgClose(dlg))"
```

It's calling the *.js

```
    function dlgClose(dlg) 
    {

        $("dlg").dialog("close");
        return false;
    }
```

`dgl` is the id of the "div" that contains an "iframe" placed in a "content" within the master page, I have parent window that searches and posts the results in the jquery dialog, makes changes, saves it and I can't seem to close the dialog.

Answer (score 3):

Updated code for you

//for object

```
function dlgClose(dlg) {
    $(dlg).dialog("close");
    return false;
 }
```

//or if its and id than

```
function dlgClose(dlg) {
    $('#'+dlg).dialog("close");
    return false;
 }
```

Comment: It still gives the same error "this object does not support this action".

Answer (score 1):

```
onclick ="window.parent(dlgClose(dlg))"
```

That onclick is wrong, it is calling the function in the current window scope.

```
onclick ="window.parent.dlgClose('dlg')"
```

That also assumes dlg is correct, not sure what that is supposed to be exactly.

Comment: it works thx both of you for your help, dlg is decribed above, it is the id of the div in the masterpage.master.